# Involution elements in infinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups, involutions

In [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Involutions_are_either_conjugate_or_have_an_involution_centralizing_both_of_them), involutions in a finite group are either conjugate or have an involution centralizing both of them. I wonder if there are similar results for an infinite group. I think and look for it but I can't finish it. When I read this proof, I wonder if a product of two involutions can be written as a commutator. Thanks for all your support.

Comment: It can be generalised to infinite periodic groups, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=NPpwVBCxVgUC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=Involutions+are+either+conjugate+or+have+an+involution+centralizing+both+of+them+for+infinite+groups&source=bl&ots=xYN0M4lST7&sig=ACfU3U0CK00didDv9BNpi4pKYNFftwMxCA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiI3bLW_vjyAhUAh_0HHY3UDVMQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=Involutions%20are%20either%20conjugate%20or%20have%20an%20involution%20centralizing%20both%20of%20them%20for%20infinite%20groups&f=false), Theorem 2.9.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thank you so much. If an element is a commutator of involutions, then it is clearly a product of two involutions. But I wonder if this converse is true. I can't prove it right or give any counterexamples.

Comment: Hence for general groups the conclusion can be written as follows: $x,y$ are conjugate or $x,y$ are centralized by some element of order 2 or $xy$ has infinite order.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven it's not an "iff": for instance think of $D_\infty\times \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ (they commute with a third element of order 2), or $x,yxy$ in the infinite dihedral group (which are conjugate and have product of infinite order).

Comment: @TrầnNamSơn In abelian groups an element can be the product of two involutions and of course cannot be a commutator of two involutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x,y$ in a group satisfy $x^2=y^2=1$. Then (as David Craven wrote in an erased comment) one has one of the following:

1. $x$ and $y$ are conjugate;
2. there exists $z$ of order 2 commuting with both $x$ and $y$;
3. $xy$ has infinite order.

Indeed, if $xy$ has finite odd order, then (1) holds. If $xy$ has finite even order, then (2) holds. And otherwise (3) holds.

In addition, no condition can be removed, as generators in various dihedral groups show. Also, in suitable groups and pairs, any two of these conditions can be satisfied without the third, or all three simultaneously.